# What is the difference html attribute "id" and "class" when implementing e.pageX and e.pageY

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, I got some codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Learning JQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq_files/myjQuery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="hover_over_event">

        <div id="hoverdiv"></div><br />

        <p><img class="hover" src="../img/Linux-Pinguino.png" hovertext="A lovely Penguin"/></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is myjQuery.js:

```
$('.hover').mousemove(function(e) {
    var hovertext = $(this).attr('hovertext');

    $('#hoverdiv').text('('+e.pageX+10+', '+e.pageY+10+')').show();
    $('#hoverdiv').css('top', e.pageY+10).css('left', e.pageX+10);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#hoverdiv').hide();
});
```

I prefer to keep that function. So I was planning to change the id="hoverdiv" to class="hoverdiv"; and the selector in the js file will be $('.hoverdiv').

Previously, it worked fine. The hint text can follow the cursor and demonstrate the location. But when I changed it into class, the hint text will be stuck in the top-left side, though the location is changing as I was moving the cursor in the picture. And I opened the Chrome developer, I could see: `<div class="hoverdiv" style="top: 218px; left: 666px; display: block;">(65610, 20810)</div>`

top, left keep changing but the text just stay in the top-left.

Anyone know which part goes wrong?

P.S.: I changed it to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Learning JQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq_files/myjQuery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="hover_over_event">

        <div class="hoverdiv"></div><br />

        <p><img class="hover" src="../img/Linux-Pinguino.png" hovertext="A lovely Penguin"/></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the js file:

```
$('.hover').mousemove(function(e) {
        var hovertext = $(this).attr('hovertext');

        $('.hoverdiv').text('('+e.pageX+10+', '+e.pageY+10+')').show();
        $('.hoverdiv').css('top', e.pageY+10).css('left', e.pageX+10);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.hoverdiv').hide();
    });
```

Comment: do you have css like position absolute attached to the id that you forgot to change to target the class?

Comment: The difference has nothing to do with how you select the element, but instead the actual element that's being selected. Make sure that changing to the class selector still returns the same content, and in the same format. It would be more helpful if you could show us the code you wrote that didn't work, so we could see the actual problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Please have a look at my update about the questioin. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID is unique for an element, CLASS is for groups of elements.
You can define class attributes in CSS to make all objects of that class look the same.

for example:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" class="myText">
<input type="text" id="text2" class="myText">
```

Comment: While this is true, I don't see how it's relevant to the OPs problem?

Comment: How STUPID I am......I forget my default.css. Inside the css file I define the style #hoverdiv{......}. Now I change it into .hoverdiv{......}. Everything is going fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple elements with the same class? because if so, the interpreter just takes the first element of that class. $(".classname") ist an array of all dom-objects, that have this class. If the class is unique, you shouldn't have a problem however.

Comment: So far, that's all in my page.